# Python - Displaying messages in ArcPy/IDLE

Tags: python, python-2.x, arcpy

I have created a wrapper for displaying messages with ArcPy and IDLE (as that is all I have available to myself due to certain circumstances) as I frequently use both to test and develop new tools. However I find myself repeating `print` statements and `arcpy` functions to display feedback.

Unfortunately, it has to be in compatible with Python 2.7.

```py
"""REMOVED HEADER"""
import sys
from time import strftime

import arcpy

def display_title(title, char_limit=100):
    # Format the title, and provide a border above and below to seperate the
    # title
    title = ("\n{0}\n{1:^" + str(char_limit) + "}\n{0}\n").format(
        "-" * char_limit, title.upper())

    # Display the title
    print(title)
    arcpy.AddMessage(title)


def display_message(message, char_limit=100):
    # Add the time to the message, and this will also run the
    # beautify_message function
    message = add_time_to_message(message, char_limit)

    # Display the message
    print(message)
    arcpy.AddMessage(message)


def display_warning(message, char_limit=100):
    # Add the time to the message, and this will also run the
    # beautify_message function
    message = add_time_to_message("WARNING: " + message, char_limit)

    # Display the message
    print(message)
    arcpy.AddWarning(message)


def display_error(message, char_limit=100, traceback=False):
    # Add the time to the message, and this will also run the
    # beautify_message function
    message = add_time_to_message("Error" + message, char_limit)

    # Add the Python traceback information (if available)
    if traceback:
        tracebackInfo = traceback.format_exc()
        if tracebackInfo != "None\n":
            message += "\n\nPython Traceback Information:\n"
            message += tracebackInfo

    # Display the message
    print(message)
    arcpy.AddError(message)

    # Terminate the Script now
    sys.exit()


def display_parameters(parameters, char_limit=100):
    # Make sure that the input type is correct
    if isinstance(parameters, tuple) or isinstance(parameters, list):
        if len(parameters) > 1:
            # Then there is more than one, print a list
            var_string = "Parameter list:\n"
            for var in parameters:
                var_string += "{} = {}\n".format(var[0], var[1])
            # Remove the last "\n"
            var_string[:-1]
        else:
            var_string = "{} = {}".format(parameters[0][0], parameters[0][1])

        # Format the message string
        message = add_time_to_message(var_string, char_limit)

        # Display the message
        print(message)
        arcpy.AddMessage(message)


# Format the message so it displays nicely within the progress box
def beautify_message(message, char_limit=100):
    # Create an empty list of beautified lines
    processed_lines = []

    # Split the message into lines that are defined with a new line
    split_message = message.split("\n")

    # Loop through the each split line
    for line in split_message:

        # Set the counter to zero
        counter = 0

        # Loop though each split line to check the length
        while len(line) > char_limit:
            # Then this line is too long, split it up
            split_line = line[counter:(counter + 1) * char_limit]

            # Capture the last space just in case
            space = True if split_line[-1] == " " else 0

            # Split it on spaces
            split_line = split_line.split()

            # Add the chunk to lines
            processed_lines.append(" ".join(split_line[:-1]))

            # Take the left over bit and add it back to line
            line = split_line[-1] + " " * space + line[(
                counter + 1) * char_limit:]

        # Add the last bit to lines
        processed_lines.append(line)

    # Return the final output
    return processed_lines


# Add the timestamp and indent message
def add_time_to_message(message, char_limit=100):
    # Determine the current time in string format to be included in some 
    # messages
    current_time = strftime("%x %X") + " - "

    # Determine the limit for each line if including the time
    limit = char_limit - len(current_time)

    # Break the message up into lines of the right length
    lines = beautify_message(message, limit)

    # Add the time and the first line
    message = current_time + lines[0] + "\n"

    # Add the rest of the lines
    for line in lines[1:]:
        message += " " * len(current_time) + line + "\n"

    # Remove the extra "\n" character
    message = message[:-1]

    # Return the final output
    return message
```

Any and all constructive criticism welcome!